# Android Graphical Layout editor black main window with custom layout

Tags: android, layout, editor

I´m currently testing out a "ScalingLinearLayout" that I found in a blog post.
http://www.quadra-tec.net/~floppie/blag/2013/01/scalinglinearlayout-auto-scaling-layouts-in-android/.

My issue is that the Main preview window of the graphical layout editor is black, while the other windows show a preview (see image below).

I´ve seen similar behavior earlier with custom components, but in my experience it is always the case that nothing is shown at all.

Has anyone seen this behavior before and knows what causes it?

Please also see the related code below

[image]

The sample layout in the image:

```
<com.nightfox.testapp.ScalingLinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".FlowA1" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="640px"
    android:layout_height="960px"
    android:gravity="center|bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/no_set_alarm" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/no_set_alarm" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The custom ScalingLinearLayout looks like this:

```
package com.nightfox.testapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class ScalingLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
int baseWidth;
int baseHeight;
boolean alreadyScaled;
float scale;
int expectedWidth;
int expectedHeight;

public ScalingLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);

    Log.d("notcloud.view", "ScalingLinearLayout: width=" + this.getWidth() + ", height=" + this.getHeight());
    this.alreadyScaled = false;
}

public ScalingLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
    super(context, attributes);

    Log.d("notcloud.view", "ScalingLinearLayout: width=" + this.getWidth() + ", height=" + this.getHeight());
    this.alreadyScaled = false;
}

public void onFinishInflate() {
    Log.d("notcloud.view", "ScalingLinearLayout::onFinishInflate: 1 width=" + this.getWidth() + ", height=" + this.getHeight());

    // Do an initial measurement of this layout with no major restrictions on size.
    // This will allow us to figure out what the original desired width and height are.
    this.measure(1000, 1000); // Adjust this up if necessary.
    this.baseWidth = this.getMeasuredWidth();
    this.baseHeight = this.getMeasuredHeight();
    Log.d("notcloud.view", "ScalingLinearLayout::onFinishInflate: 2 width=" + this.getWidth() + ", height=" + this.getHeight());

    Log.d("notcloud.view", "ScalingLinearLayout::onFinishInflate: alreadyScaled=" + this.alreadyScaled);
    Log.d("notcloud.view", "ScalingLinearLayout::onFinishInflate: scale=" + this.scale);
    if(this.alreadyScaled) {
        Scale.scaleViewAndChildren((LinearLayout)this, this.scale, 0);
    }
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Get the current width and height.
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();

    // Figure out if we need to scale the layout.
    // We may need to scale if:
    //    1. We haven't scaled it before.
    //    2. The width has changed.
    //    3. The height has changed.
    if(!this.alreadyScaled || width != this.expectedWidth || height != this.expectedHeight) {
        // Figure out the x-scaling.
        float xScale = (float)width / this.baseWidth;
        if(this.alreadyScaled && width != this.expectedWidth) {
            xScale = (float)width / this.expectedWidth;
        }
        // Figure out the y-scaling.
        float yScale = (float)height / this.baseHeight;
        if(this.alreadyScaled && height != this.expectedHeight) {
            yScale = (float)height / this.expectedHeight;
        }

        // Scale the layout.
        this.scale = Math.min(xScale, yScale);
        Log.d("notcloud.view", "ScalingLinearLayout::onLayout: Scaling!");
        Scale.scaleViewAndChildren((LinearLayout)this, this.scale, 0);

        // Mark that we've already scaled this layout, and what
        // the width and height were when we did so.
        this.alreadyScaled = true;
        this.expectedWidth = width;
        this.expectedHeight = height;

        // Finally, return.
        return;
    }

    super.draw(canvas);
}
```

}

and the Scale class:

```
package com.nightfox.testapp;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Scale {
public static void scaleContents(View rootView, View container) {
    Scale.scaleContents(rootView, container, rootView.getWidth(), rootView.getHeight());
}

// Scales the contents of the given view so that it completely fills the given
// container on one axis (that is, we're scaling isotropically).
public static void scaleContents(View rootView, View container, int width, int height) {
    Log.d("notcloud.scale", "Scale::scaleContents: container: " + container.getWidth() + "x" + container.getHeight() + ".");

    // Compute the scaling ratio
    float xScale = (float)container.getWidth() / width;
    float yScale = (float)container.getHeight() / height;
    float scale = Math.min(xScale, yScale);

    // Scale our contents
    Log.d("notcloud.scale", "Scale::scaleContents: scale=" + scale + ", width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ".");
    scaleViewAndChildren(rootView, scale, 0);
}

// Scale the given view, its contents, and all of its children by the given factor.
public static void scaleViewAndChildren(View root, float scale, int canary) {
    // Retrieve the view's layout information
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = root.getLayoutParams();

    // Scale the View itself
    if(layoutParams.width != ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT && layoutParams.width != ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
        layoutParams.width *= scale;
    }
    if(layoutParams.height != ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT && layoutParams.height != ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
        layoutParams.height *= scale;
    }

    // If the View has margins, scale those too
    if(layoutParams instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)layoutParams;
        marginParams.leftMargin *= scale;
        marginParams.topMargin *= scale;
        marginParams.rightMargin *= scale;
        marginParams.bottomMargin *= scale;
    }
    root.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    // Same treatment for padding
    root.setPadding(
        (int)(root.getPaddingLeft() * scale),
        (int)(root.getPaddingTop() * scale),
        (int)(root.getPaddingRight() * scale),
        (int)(root.getPaddingBottom() * scale)
    );

    // If it's a TextView, scale the font size
    /*
    if(root instanceof TextView) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)root;
        tv.setTextSize(tv.getTextSize() * scale); //< We do NOT want to do this.
    }
    */

    // If it's a ViewGroup, recurse!
    if(root instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)root;
        for(int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
            scaleViewAndChildren(vg.getChildAt(i), scale, canary + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have edited the theme of that particular xml file. you just need to click on your desire xml and change its theme from the theme option right in the center of the screen right side from the nexus S selection of yours... or u can goto res>values>strings and change the string responsible for theme selection.

Comment: or possibly your theme is black but you have manually set the background to white as shown in your xml file given above

Comment: I tried changing the theme around to a bunch of different alternatives, but I still don´t see the layout. If I for example select Theme.Light, the screen becomes white instead of black, but I still don´t see my components

Comment: replace this line of you xml layout **android:background="#FFFFFF"** with this **android:background="#66FFFFFF"** if you found the change then probably u need to remove this line..

Comment: After some time going through the code I´ve figured out that it seems to be related to the code rather than to the layout. The graphical editor does not seem to recognize the call to super.draw(canvas); in the ScalingLinearLayout class above, and thus, the layout is never drawn. However it does work when running on a regular device.